# Non setter/getter methods in proxy interface

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is there a way where I can put non setter/getter methods inside the proxy interface that we define?

For eg..

```
@ProxyFor( value = requestFactory.example.gwt.server.domain.Person.class )
public interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    String getLastName();

    String getFirstName();

    void setLastName( String nachname );

    void setFirstName( String vorname );

    public Long getId();

    public Integer getVersion();

    void setProperty(String name, Object value);

}
```

The last method in the above example throws an exception "Only setters and getters allowed". Any ways to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Proxies can only have getters and setters.

You can however add a method to a `RequestContext` for the same server-side call to be made:

```java
InstanceRequest<PersonProxy> setProperty(String name, String value);
```

Used as:

```java
context.setProperty("foo", "bar").using(personProxy);
```

Note that you cannot use `Object` either (and before you ask: no, you cannot have overloads so you'd have to add `setPropertyString`, `setPropertyDate`, `setPropertyDouble`, etc. with similarly named methods on the server-side)